# Convert date dd-mm-yyyy value to text of YYYYMMDD

Tags: vba, date

I have to convert the below date fields (dd-mm-yyyy) to YYYYMMDD format.

```
Column A     Column B
30.08.2013    
25.08.2012
```

and so on

In Column B, I want the answer as

```
Column B
20130830 
20120825
```

The format is text format, i.e. `text(date,"YYYYMMDD")`.  Range B will proceed till range A has values.

Can someone help me get the right code?

Comment: Format(string, formatMask) is the function you are looking for. But why not just use the Text function in a formula?

Answer (score 0):

In-cell formula could be written like so and copy the formula all the way down till you have data in column A.

```
=RIGHT(A1,4) & LEFT(RIGHT(A1,7),2) & LEFT(A1, 2)
```

VBA Macro would look like this:

```
Sub ConvertDate()
    Range("B1").Value = Right(Range("A1").Value, 4) & _
                        Left(Right(Range("A1").Value, 7), 2) & _
                        Left(Range("A1").Value, 2)
End Sub
```

You can change the code to suit your needs so that the macro automatically formats date in column B. It is much simpler to use a formula than use a macro.